# Creating a SSM Composite Document that pulls Parameters from Parameter Store - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

The task is simple: whenever an EC2 instance is launched with tag key:value I want it to install a specific software. Whenever an EC2 instance is launched with a different tag key:value I want it to install a different software.

I understand that I can create 2 different associations in State Manager that uses runCommand RuneRemoteScript to install software based on the tags, but the goal is to have 1 composite document that can do this.

Any help / guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using SSM Automation documents - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-branchdocs.html

However, probably you will need to do something like this:

1. In the State Manager use `AWS-RunDocument`,
2. This document should execute SSM Automation document (your Composite document)
3. Your Composite document should look like this:

`I didn't validate this template, and I assume It shouldn't work without a few days of debugging`

```
schemaVersion: '0.3'
parameters:
  InstanceId:
    type: String
mainSteps:
  - name: DescribeEc2
    action: 'aws:executeScript'
    inputs:
      Runtime: python3.7
      Handler: script_handler
      Script: |
        import json
        import boto3


        def script_handler(events):
            ec2_instance = boto3.client('ec2').describe_instances(
                InstanceIds=events["instance_id"],
            )["Reservations"][0]["Instances"][0]

            # thread it like an example,
            # Here you should parse your tags and decide what software you
            # want to install on the provided instance
            
            return json.dumps(
                {
                    "to_be_installed": "result"
                },
                sort_keys=True,
                default=str
            )

      InputPayload:
        instance_id: '{{ InstanceId }}'
    Outputs:
      - Name: result
        Selector: "$.to_be_installed"

  - name: WhatToInstall
    action: aws:branch
    inputs:
      Choices:
      - NextStep: InstallSoft1
        Variable: "{{DescribeEc2.result}}"
        StringEquals: soft_1
      - NextStep: InstallSoft1
        Variable: "{{DescribeEc2.result}}"
        StringEquals: soft_2

  - name: InstallSoft1
    action: aws:runCommand
    inputs:
      DocumentName: AWS-RunShellScript
      InstanceIds:
      - '{{ InstanceId }}'
      Parameters:
        commands:
        ...
  - name: InstallSoft2
    action: aws:runCommand
    inputs:
      DocumentName: AWS-RunShellScript
      InstanceIds:
      - '{{ InstanceId }}'
      Parameters:
        commands:
        ...
```

Tbh, you will find a lot of troubles with such solution (IAM and SSM specific issues), so I will recommend using `Event Bridge` -> `Lambda Function`(that decides which Document/Automation should be run) -> `SSM-RunDocument` (executed directly in the `Lambda Function`).